# Dummy variable only for character value in a column (Neglecting float and integers)

Tags: logistic-regression, dummy-variables

My dataset consists of 3000 rows and 50 columns, out of which one column (*ESTIMATE_FAMILY_CONTRIBUTION*)  contains all numerical value(around 2000 different values like 20,30,32....) but got one value as String e.g. *'No_information'*.

When I create dummies(One-Hot Encoded) for the Feature *(pd.get_dummies())*, around 2000 new columns are created for the original column *i.e. ESTIMATE_FAMILY_CONTRIBUTION*.

What I want is to have only 2 columns to be created, one for *'No_information'* and other with all the numerical values. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2000 different values available for a dataset of 3000. I don't think you should treat that as a Categorical column.

*Treat "No_information" as a NaN and impute using the best-suited strategy using the relation with other columns*

## Edit post comment

If you want to treat it as Categorical, I will suggest

- Create *"bins"* of values *e.g. <50- Very Low, 50-500 - Medium, etc.*

-  Then create One-Hot encoded data

-  With this approach too, *"No_information"* should be treated as NaN. The reason being that when Info is not available it could have been anything *i.e. Low, High, Medium.* Treating it as 4th value will have lesser information.

 - Try different bins/approaches and see which produce the best result

*Dealing with High cardinality of Categorical feature -*

- Search internet/SE with *"Encode feature with very high cardinality"*. This is a known challenge, you will get plenty of resources.

 - Try other encoding approaches. See these links -

*[Beyond OHE](http://www.willmcginnis.com/2015/11/29/beyond-one-hot-an-exploration-of-categorical-variables/)

[Library](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders)

[kaggle post](https://www.kaggle.com/waydeherman/tutorial-categorical-encoding)*

Comment: actually i am being asked specifically to treat this column with "No_information". and create a model with dummies. How to do it?

Comment: Thank you so much , you solved my problem.

Comment: Please mark the Answer as "Accepted"